# Changing Toolbar Background Results in Lavendar color

Tags: android

Trying to change the toolbar background color. Here is how it originally gets set:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/color_primary"
    app:menu="@menu/toolbar_menu" />
```

And it looks like this:

[image]

Then I move to a different fragment and I want to change that color, which I do via view model. MainActivity is observing the live data and is notified of this color event:

Fragment

```
appViewModel.toolbarBackgroundColor.value = R.color.black
```

MainActivity

```
appViewModel.toolbarBackgroundColor.observe(this, { color ->
    // toolbar.setBackgroundColor(color)
    toolbar.background = ColorDrawable(color)
})
```

Everything flows correctly, and the observer is responding. But the tool bar, instead of rendering in black, looks like this:

[image]

What I am doing wrong as I try to get the toolbar to have a black background?

Comment: Try with: `ContextCompat.getColor(context,color)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> appViewModel.toolbarBackgroundColor.value = R.color.black

`appViewModel.toolbarBackgroundColor.value` expects an integer representing a color.

`R.color.black` delivers the resource ID not the color value.

Apparently the resource ID of your black color equals a lavender color :D

---

Use either

```
getResources().getColor(R.color.black)
```

or

```
ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.black)
```

Comment: I knew it was something like that! Thanks!